# store json object to azure table storage entity using azure data factory pipeline

Tags: json, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory, dataflow

I've created one azure data factory pipeline. By which, I need to store my JSON file content as string from my blob storage JSON file to azure table storage entity.

I tried with copy activity where the source is my blob storage JSON file and destination is my azure table storage's table where I need to store that.

Finally, I need the content of my JSON file to an entity of table storage as below.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can copy data from a blob storage JSON file to Azure table by having the source and the sink in the copy activity.

In the mapping tab of the copy activity, you can define the mapping between the attributes of the JSON file and the table as shown below :
[image]

Comment: But in above situation, I can not store 'data' json with all data(id, email...) in single column. As you defined above, which will map to different column of an entity.

Comment: That is correct Manish. You can map an attribute to a column in the table. If you wish to store the entire JSON response in a field, you can have a web activity to get the JSON response and store it in a blob file and then copy it using a copy activity with the required mapping.

Comment: i have done it, but still the array column does not land into the storage table :(